# Hide documentation panel permanently

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider

I just installed Rider on my machine.

```
JetBrains Rider 2017.3.1
Build #RD-173.3994.2442, built on February 5, 2018
Licensed to Rider Evaluator
Expiration date: March 21, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b10 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Unfortunately, the following panel keeps getting on my way every time I move the mouse pointer.

[image]

I've tried every option in its menu with no luck. I managed to resize it to 1x1 pixel, which is a workaround, but I'd like to properly hide it permanently.

My online searches were not fruitful so far.

Comment: No a Rider user .. but have you searched for `documentation` in Settings? This IDE is IDEA-based ... so it should have search functionality on all Settings .. and there is one option responsible for such behaviour.

Comment: For example: in PhpStorm it will be `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General --> Show quick documentation on mouse move`

Comment: @LazyOne Your second comment did the trick! Could you please post as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Rider user, but have you searched for "documentation" in the settings? Rider is an IDEA-based IDE, so it should have search functionality on all Settings similar to other IDEs of this family that have an option responsible for such behaviour.

For example: in PhpStorm it would be `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General --> Show quick documentation on mouse move`.